# IS there a way to download all the sql code created in MicroStrategy into a document OUTSIDE of MicroStrategy

Tags: microstrategy

I want to be able to download all SQL code for all reports that exist in my MicroStrategy environment into a folder on my personal folder on the network or the c: drive. IS it possible? or is there a table that I can access in MicroStrategy that has all the sql code stored?

Comment: Which MSTR version do you use? If it is recent enough (2021 for sure, 2020U3+ afair but not sure) you can check out "mstrio-py" and the examples. You can retrieve all reports/cubes (aka datasets) and the corresponding SQL this way. If needed I can provide something you can use as a starting point.

Comment: We use the recent verion .What is "mstrio_py"? if you have something that I can use as a starting point, Iwilbe very greatful.

Answer (score 0):

The python package ["mstrio-py"](https://github.com/MicroStrategy/mstrio-py) makes it easier to get this kind of information from the API. A guide for how to install/use with some examples can also be found there.

As far as I can see the API does not expose report-sql-views. But there is this [KB article](https://community.microstrategy.com/s/article/KB12851-How-to-retrieve-report-SQL-without-executing-the-report?language=en_US) which might be of help if you need those too.

Below is a quick sample I used recently mash some of the info together.

NOTE: There is a difference in what you might be interested in, the SQL of a "fresh run" vs the SQL a (cube)cache instance has been run with.

```
from mstrio.connection import Connection
from mstrio.admin.application import Environment, Application, compare_application_settings
from mstrio.cube import Cube
from mstrio.report import Report
from mstrio.admin import dataset
from typing import Union, List
from json.decoder import JSONDecodeError

#connection info
base_url = "https://HOST:PORT/MicroStrategyLibrary/api"
username = "USERNAME"
password = "PASSWORD"
project = "PROJECTNAME"
conn = Connection(base_url, username, password, project_name=project, login_mode=1) #1==standard login
env = Environment(connection=conn)

#do not filter subtype if you want to include user-uploaded cubes
datasets = dataset.list_datasets(connection=conn, subtype=[776])

# ROUTE1
# this only shows the SQL that would be used if you ran the cube right now. if you want to check what has been used use ROUTE2
# extra call for every sqlView is needed
for i,cube in enumerate(datasets,0):
    with conn.session.get(url=conn.base_url + '/api/v2/cubes/' + cube.id + '/sqlView') as res:
        try:
            z.append((datasets[i], res.json()))
        except JSONDecodeError:
            print("Error")

# ROUTE2
# alternatively grab every cached cube from monitor to get cache-ids. this is a bit different, this will show you the SQL of the data you already have retrieved
response = conn.session.get(url=f'{conn.base_url}/api/monitors/caches/cubes',
                      params={'clusterNode': IS_NODE_NAME,
                             'projectIds': conn.project_id})
monitor_caches = response.json()

# grab info for every cube cache found, there is a lot of additional info available
for cache in monitor_caches['cubeCaches']:
    response = conn.session.get(f'{conn.base_url}/api/monitors/caches/cubes/{cache["id"]}',
                                headers={'X-MSTR-ProjectID': conn.project_id})
    monitor_cube_instance = response.json()
    #there may be multiple passes, simply appending might not be a good strategy
    cube_cache_sql = ', '.join([x['sqlStatement'] for x in monitor_cube_instance['jobExecutionStatistics']['queryPasseInfos']])
```